# Why are my sparklines not rendering with xlsxwriter?

Tags: xlsxwriter

I'm trying to add a column of sparklines, where the data range for each row is a corresponding part of a row from another sheet. The statement I have, for example, is:

```python
summary_sheet.add_sparkline(row, c, {'range': "Home Values!B2:B10", 'markers': True})
```

I know my data ranges and row-col indices are correct, but it throws an error and the output excel is corrupted. Is it an issue with the sheet name having spaces?

Comment: Assuming you are setting the worksheet name to 'Home Values' this will cause an issue I think becauase of the space in the name. You should set the sheet name to 'HomeValues' and use **summary_sheet.add_sparkline(row, c, {'range': "HomeValues!B2:B10", 'markers': True})**

Comment: Yes, the space in the name is probably the issue. It should be single quoted like in Excel: `"'Home Values'!B2:B10"`

Comment: Note also the default sparkline will be 'line' so you must specify column as the type. **summary_sheet.add_sparkline(row, c, {'type': 'column', 'range': "'Home Values'!B2:B10", 'markers': True})**

Comment: Ah, adding single quotes around the sheet name fixed it.